# How do i get Column AutoSize functionality to work with ListView, using Visual Studio and C# Win Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a WinForm I'm creating using Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop in C#.

On the Main form I have a ListView Control with 3 Columns that I added through the VS Properties Window, I want the user to be able to resize the form at their leisure, this works fine so long as they don't exceed the width of all 3 columns added together, once that happens an empty fourth column with no header text shows up and just continues to grow as long as you keep resizing.  I end up having 4 columns of which I did not create the last one, as im sure you've figured by now the listview is anchored so that it will expand when the form is resized.  I want the listview to expand but I don't want a fourth column, is there a way to allow one of the columns to resize itself / autofill when the form is resized?

Comment: Looks like you have to do this manually. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377246/listview-final-column-autosize-creates-scrollbar) and its answers for some ideas. You could also switch to DataGridView and then you can just set the last column to 100% width.

Comment: Blorgbeard is right but, there is no option to set column width 100% if you are using simple windows form. you should set the `SizeMode` property in `DefaultCellStyle` property to `Fill`. That will automatically fillup the empty area of your grid with that particular column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in `ListView_Resize` event.

```
int ColumnIndex = 3; //assign the column index which you want to set autosize
int iWidth = 0; 
for ( int i = 0 ; i < ListView1.Columns.Count ; i++ )
{
    if (ColumnIndex == i)  
        continue;
    iWidth += ListView1.Columns[i].Width;  //Calculating all column width
}
ListView1.Columns[ColumnIndex].Width = ListView1.Width - iWidth;
```